# Property creator function

Tags: python, properties

I would like to have a function in an object that creates a member of a certain behavior. Similarly to using the @property decorator. But without having to declare the getter and the setter function. I would like to create many members of a custom behaviour with the same getter and setter functions. However this example does not work. When I run it, the `new_prop` member is a property object, not a member. How can I achieve my goal?

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_prop("my_prop1")
        self.new_prop("my_prop2")
        self.new_prop("my_prop3")

    def new_prop(self, name):
        def getter(self):
            this_prop = getattr(self, "_" + name)
            if this_prop is None:
                return "This is None!"
            else:
                return this_prop
        def setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, "_" + name, value)
        setattr(self, name, property(getter, setter))
        setattr(self, "_" + name, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_class = MyClass()

    print(type(my_class.my_prop1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property` is a descriptor, and like all descriptors it is only invoked when resolved as a class attribute - as you discovered, when it's an instance attribute, it's `__get__` and `__set__` methods are not invoked.

If your point is only to avoid rewriting the same getters and setters for N properties, the plain simple solution is to write your own descriptor:

```
class MyProp(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        value = getattr(obj, "_" + self.name)
        if value is None:
           return "This is None!"
        else:
           return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, "_" + self.name, value)


class Foo(object):
    prop1 = MyProp("prop1")
    prop2 = MyProp("prop2")
```

Comment: Is there any way to use your solution in a way that I don't have to write 'prop1 = MyProp("prop1")' but instead something like: 'add_prop("prop1")'

Comment: Nope - or at least not without some very nasty hack, and even then... This has to do with the way the `class` statement works and how class objects are built - basically, the `class` statement execute all statements at the top-level of the `class` block, collects all names created in this block in a dict, passes this dict to `type()`, and binds the resulting class object to the class name in the enclosing namespace. This means that the class does not yet exists when executing the `prop1 = MyProp(...)` statement, so `MyProp` cannot access it.

Comment: Why does the class return self when obj = None?

Comment: @Benjamin since this descriptor relies on the instance for data storage, it cannot return any meaningful value when looked up on the class. Returning self is the canonical behaviour in this case, cf the builtin `property` type.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a property is declared as a class attribute. So you have to set it on the class, not the instance:

```
setattr(self.__class__, name, property(getter, setter))
```

Whether this is useful is another question, particularly setting a class attribute in `__init__` for every instance. You should consider implementing your own descriptor outside of the class, so that you can do:

```
class MyClass():
     my_prop1 = new_prop("my_prop1")
     my_prop2 = new_prop("my_prop2")
     my_prop3 = new_prop("my_prop3")
```